# How to write the output of a command in netcat to a file?

Tags: bash, python-2.7, paramiko, netcat

I am executing a command in localhost using Paramiko's exec_command and trying to write the output from localhost to a file.

I tried the following command,

```
stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('echo "command" |nc localhost 6666 > /opt/doc/Output.txt 2>&1')
```

The command is successfully executed and the result of the command is also being written for the first time. When executed repeatedly, it does not write. I need to close and open the server and then run the command again.

Comment: Are you executing a command on localhost via SSH? `subprocess` is invented for such things.

Comment: yeah ssh client

Comment: I mean it's a bit strange :) if you want to execute a command on _local_ machine, why not use `subprocess`? SSH requires authentication, at least one drawback, and `subprocess` was intended to be used for exactly this type of tasks

Comment: I meant, i am executing a command on  6666 in a remote server. So i use SSH to connect to the server.